# StringUtils.split() returns an empty string?

Tags: java, string-utils

Can StringUtils.split function in java return an empty string for input other than an empty string ?

Comment: No. From Docs- "Returns: an array of parsed Strings, null if null String input"

Comment: as StringUtils.split returns null only for null input, you may be using it incorrectly. post your code that uses StringUtils.split

Answer (score 0):

According to Doc, NO. Only a `null` input string will return `null`.

There are three versions of `StringUtils.split()`:

Splits the provided text into an array, using whitespace as the separator

```
public static String[] split(String str)
```

Splits the provided text into an array, separator specified. This is an alternative to using StringTokenizer.

```
public static String[] split(String str, char separatorChar)
```

Splits the provided text into an array, separators specified. This is an alternative to using StringTokenizer.

```
public static String[] split(String str, String separatorChars)
```

Answer (score 0):

No , it will not return empty String "" for non-empty String. i believe you are talking about string with zero length "" , not about null.